# Unable to add Linux slave machine from Jenkins windows box

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on windows box and when I try to add a Linux slave machine I am getting an error like below.

Does anyone have any idea why this error occurs ?

```
[05/31/17 04:05:13] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to sdc00ira:22.
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.ssh\known_hosts [SSH] No Known Hosts file was found at C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.ssh\known_hosts. Please ensure one is created at this path and that Jenkins can read it.
Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.
java.io.IOException: There was a problem while connecting to sdc00ira:22
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:818)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:687)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:601)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.openConnection(SSHLauncher.java:1265)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:790)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:785)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Key exchange was not finished, connection is closed.
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.getOrWaitForConnectionInfo(KexManager.java:93)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.getConnectionInfo(TransportManager.java:230)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.Connection.connect(Connection.java:770)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The server hostkey was not accepted by the verifier callback
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.KexManager.handleMessage(KexManager.java:535)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager.receiveLoop(TransportManager.java:777)
    at com.trilead.ssh2.transport.TransportManager$1.run(TransportManager.java:489)
    ... 1 more
[05/31/17 04:05:13] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[05/31/17 04:05:13] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

Answer (score -2):

What works for me is to change "Host Key Verification Strategy" from "Known Hosts file verification strategy" to "Manually trusted key verification strategy" in node configure.